# Trouble connecting to wireless network two rooms away

Tags: networking, raspbmc, wifi, kodi

Recently I set up Raspbmc on my Pi, everything works fine so far – even WIFI if I'm next to the router (Apple Time Capsule).

Here's the problem: As soon as I plug it in my TV on the second floor it refuses to connect.
The wifi network manager shows that the signal strength is 86/100 which should be more than enough to connect!

Any Ideas how I could solve this?

Many thanks! 
Costa

Comment: http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template2/

Comment: The signal strength *from* the router may not be the issue -- the pi USB ports are under powered and there may not be enough signal *to* the router.

Comment: How are you powering your pi and the wifi adapter?

Comment: I use the standart micro USB + a externally powered USB-Hub.

Comment: What is powering the PI the TV, a power brick or adapter plugged into the wall? If you are connecting the micro usb cable directly to the TV or even the hub it may not be supplying enough current.

Comment: Is the USB Wi-Fi going through the hub or is it directly attached to the Pi? If it's directly attached, try powering it through the hub. Some adapters have too high a current draw to be connected to the ports directly.

Answer (score 1):

Electronics emit electromagnetic radiation.  WiFi is an example of such radiation.   When placing WiFi transmitters or receivers near another powerful electronic, your signal can be significantly degraded.  This is especially true for things such as speakers, or high-voltage plasma televisions.

WiFi bounces or passes through different medium.  It bounces off of glass and water.  If you have a fish tank between you and your router, it can cause severe interference.

As stated in the comments, you may be receiving your signal at a good level, but your router may not be able to receive the signal sent from your device.  Power level is a very good guess at what could be causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are too much interference and/or blocking two rooms away. Microwaves, cordless phones, baby monitors, lots of things that uses a wireless connection use the 2.4GHz band now, hence too much interference. Also, this band (and the less interfered 5GHz band too) does not take physical obstacles like walls very well, especially when the concrete wall is thick enough, with steel reinforcement in it, that can totally block the signal.

You can use some method of wired networking, like existing structure cabling or power-line communication, to either send a wired connection directly to your Pi, or set up another access point that forms wireless roaming network with your existing Time Capsule.

In my apartment I have structural cabling preinstalled during renovation and I places wireless access points at either side of the signal-blocking concrete wall to guarantee a good connection.